# How to insert a vector in the defined place of 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, insert, 2d-vector

I have a simple and two-dimensional vectors of std::string.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
std::vector<std::string> v;
```

Now how to insert v in defined position of vec?

I've tried to use `insert()` , but there was an error:

```
 vec.insert(k,v); //k -is an position of vec for inserting


no matching function for call to std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::insert(int, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)
```

Comment: what is `k` ? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: added a coment for k

Comment: cant you add a definition? comments can say anything and dont relate at all to the error message you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iterator:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
std::vector<std::string> v;
vec.insert(vec.begin(), v);
```

or:

```
vec.insert(vec.begin() + 2, v);
```

to insert at position 2, but make sure there is index 2 - ie. resize your vector : `vec.resize(3);`

From your error I see k is of type int : `insert(int,`, and you need an iterator.